# Is there a Forth static analyzer for stack effects?

Tags: forth

I'm losing productivity to programming errors that cause stack overflow.

For instance, if I omit a `drop` in an `IF ELSE THEN` branch, inside a loop, and I get a stack overflow, I usually have to reboot my development environment. I'm using [SwapForth](https://github.com/jamesbowman/swapforth) on the [iCEstick](http://www.latticesemi.com/icestick).

Does there exist a static analyzer that predicts the stack outcome of a compiled word?

Like an automated tool that checks that the code always matches the (*nnn nnn -- f*) documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such tool is known to me, but why don't we implement it?

In the general case the problem doesn't have a solution (see [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) and the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). Nevertheless, a practically useful tool obviously can be implemented. It can be a stand-alone tool or extension to your particular Forth system that checks code on the fly during compilation.

As for some example, see [Forth Wizard](http://sovietov.com/app/forthwiz.html) by Peter Sovietov (2003). This tool internally evaluates stack effect of auto-generated code.
Another example: [Stack Verification](http://clubweb.interbaun.com/~rc/Timbre/ContentPages/Timbre/StackVerification.html) paper by Rob Chapman (1997).
Also the following papers can be useful: *Type Inference in Stack Based Languages*, Bill Stoddart and  Peter J. Knaggs, 1992 ([PDF](http://www.rigwit.co.uk/papers/fac-type.pdf)); *Simple Type Inference for Higher-Order Stack-Oriented Languages*, Christopher Diggins, 2008 ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.156.406&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

Perhaps the simplest solution is just to dynamically check the stack effect (changing of the depth) and throw an exception when the stack signature is violated  (in development versions only).
The idea is to redefine `:` (and possible `;`) to obtain stack effect from stack comment and compile `EXECUTE-BALANCED` wrapper for colon-definitions.

```
: EXECUTE-EFFECT ( i*x xt -- j*x n )
  DEPTH 1- >R EXECUTE DEPTH R> -
;
: EXECUTE-BALANCED ( i*x xt n -- j*x ) \ j = i + n
  >R EXECUTE-EFFECT R> = IF EXIT THEN
  -5010 THROW \ stack is unbalanced
;
```

Evidently, such a solution can catch a mistake between words only, and it won't catch a missed `DROP` inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

An analyser would need to know the stack effect of all words used, not just standard words. In practise this means that the stack effect would have to be documented somehow for all words present. I have done this in ciforth in behalf of an optimiser, so it can be done. What I did not do is automatically compare it to a specification. This would require formalizing specifications like you proposed with *(nnn nnn - f)* , and also a way to specify indeterministic stack effect.

A halfway solution is having the stack effect colorcoding that makes stack errors standout. It uses a specification of the stack effect stored in the flag field in ciforth implementations.
https://home.hccnet.nl/a.w.m.van.der.horst/forthlectureE.html

Experienced Forthers don't think much of this. Words have to be tested immediately after creation, which make stack errors shortlived.